# WiX: Is it possible to put components into different files?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a file Product.wxs which is around 3000 lines. I have split it into different files. But some of these files are also very large and it will be a pain to maintain it. 
One of the files contains file structure and looks like that:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Component Id="ComponentId" .... >
             ....
    <Component />
 <Directory />
```

The component with Id="ComponentId" contains a lot of RegistryValues (600 lines). I would like to put this component and all of the registry values into a separate file and just reference to it. I tried ComponentRef but it doesn't work inside Directory node. 
Is there a way of doing so?
Thank you in a advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep this is basically the ideal use case for a large installation. You should be moving all the similar related components to their own wxs files so that if you ever need to modify the files included it should be easier to find them.

With wix, you can define any chunk of XML definitions in a `<Fragment>` tag. This just defines a standalone, ideally related, definition for the installer. When you compile your installer the whole entire fragment will be discarded *unless* there is a reference that ties it into your product.

I don't think you can use a ComponentRef to define the component's directory so that is probably what is causing you grief when trying to use it under a DirectoryRef tag (see [DirectoryRef](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/directoryref.html) and [ComponentRef](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/componentref.html) valid parents and children). You should be required to have either a DirectoryRef/Directory above your component definition or be using the Directory="" value for the Component tag.

To reference your component you should be either using a ComponentRef in a ComponentGroup tag or using the ComponentRef in a Feature tag.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I defined directory structure in the main file Product and I put large components into separate files under DirectoryRef. It all looks pretty nice.